# Database connection in a Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jpa, plugins

I need to do an Eclipse Plugin that connects with the data base automatically (in Eclipse it is "New -> JPA Entities from tables -> Add Connection" and put the different values).

I have been looking for about that and I have found that I have to use a connectionProfile (org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.connectionProfile, explained [there](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/project_connectivity/connectivity_doc/CMF_I101905.html) but when I have look for in Eclipse API I don't see this package and the methods that I need to do it.

How I can do this connection?

Do I need another library to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the Eclipse `Data Tools Platform`. Go to `Help > Install New Software`, 'Work with' your Eclipse release and look in the `Database Development` section for this.